# Prevent Variable Overflow from InputBox user error

Tags: vba

I was writing some code that required the user to input a number, which was then stored in a variable.  While testing the code I input a number larger than the variable type would allow and I got an variable overflow error.  So I wrote this code to prevent that from happening. It works, but I was hoping there was a more concise way to do it, or even a function already part of VBA that I could use.

```
Sub PreventOverflow()

    Dim IsThisANumber As String
    Dim Number As Integer
    Dim PreventOverflow As Long
    Dim Cancel As VbMsgBoxResult

    Number = 0
    PreventOverflow = 0

    IsThisANumber = InputBox("Enter a number less than 32768")

    Do While Number = 0

        Do While PreventOverflow = 0
            If IsNumeric(IsThisANumber) = True Then
                If Len(IsThisANumber) < 6 Then
                    PreventOverflow = IsThisANumber
                Else
                    IsThisANumber = InputBox("Your number was not less than 32768" & vbNewLine & "Please enter a number less than 32768")
                    PreventOverflow = 0
                End If
            ElseIf IsThisANumber <> "" Then
                IsThisANumber = InputBox("Your did not enter a number" & vbNewLine & "Plese enter a number less than 32768")
                PreventOverflow = 0
            Else
                Cancel = MsgBox("You did not enter a number.  Do you want to continue?", vbYesNo)
                If Cancel = vbNo Then
                    Exit Sub
                Else
                    IsThisANumber = InputBox("Enter a number less than 32768")
                    PreventOverflow = 0
                End If
            End If
        Loop

        If PreventOverflow < 1 Or PreventOverflow > 32767 Then
            IsThisANumber = InputBox("Your number was not less than 32768" & vbNewLine & "Please enter a number less than 32768")
            PreventOverflow = 0
        Else
            Number = PreventOverflow
        End If
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: How are you calling this code? Shouldn't it be a `Function` procedure that returns the user input?

Comment: I actually haven't created my own functions, so I'm not familiar with that, but I know the basic idea.  If I turned this code into a `Function` instead of a `Sub` would the it still work in the same way?  I guess my question is, what is the difference between `Function` and `Sub`?   But yes, ideally this would be a function, that I could call.

Comment: A `Function` is a procedure that returns a value to the caller, much like `Len`, `IsNumeric`, `InputBox` and `MsgBox` are. You would have to remove the `Dim PreventOverflow As Long` declaration though, because it having the same name as the function it's declared in would be a compile error (*duplicate definition in current scope*), because you assign a function's return value by assigning the function's identifier - so you can't have a local variable in a function with the same name as that function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you over engineered this function a bit, which is easy to do. Simply store your value in a `variant` to check if it will fit in an integer.

```
 Private Function IsInteger(ByVal prompt As String) As Integer
    Dim longHolder As Variant
    longHolder = InputBox(prompt)
    If IsNumeric(longHolder) Then
        If Int(longHolder) = CDbl(longHolder) Then
            If Abs(longHolder) < 32768 Then
                IsInteger = longHolder
            Else
                MsgBox "Too Big"
                IsInteger = 0
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox "Decimals!"
            IsInteger = 0
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "Not a number"
        IsInteger = 0
    End If
End Function
```

You would use it like this

```
Sub test()
    Dim x As Integer
    x = IsInteger("give me an integer")
End Sub
```

---

That being said, [integers are obsolete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409117/why-use-integer-instead-of-long/26409520#26409520). According to [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa164506(v=office.10).aspx) VBA *silently* converts all integers to `long`. So, just use `Long` to begin with.

Comment: One more question.  In the fifth line, why did you use `Int(longHolder) = CDbl(longHolder)` instead of just `Int(longHolder) = longHolder`?   If the user entered a decimal, wouldn't VBA store the data in `longHolder` as a decimal?

Comment: @JacobBischoff because `longHolder` is a variant, when you enter a number, it's stored as a string. So your thinking is a very common thread (I fell into it writing this answer), but if you try it out with variant the `int` will not match the naked variable. Nor would the dbl match the naked variable. It holds true for both integers and decimals